# How to merge nodes when they appear in multiple columns in Graphistry

Tags: python, pandas, graph, visualization

I am trying to construct a hypergraph via Graphistry from this dataframe:

```
data = [
    ["Jack", "Lauren", "Brian"],
    ["Lauren", "Brian", "Jaden"],
    ["Brian", "Jaden", "Tessa"],
]

names_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Previous", "Current", "Next"])

hg1 = graphistry.hypergraph(names_df, entity_types=["Previous", "Current", "Next"])

hg1_g = hg1["graph"]
hg1_g.plot()
```

The problem is that the nodes are treated as different each time they appear in the various columns.

I would like to get 5 different nodes and 3 edges, one for each row in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge node that appear in different columns, you can specify categories with the `opts` kwarg. Moreover, you can draw your edges directly between nodes by specifying `direct=True`:

```
data = [
    ["Jack", "Lauren", "Brian"],
    ["Lauren", "Brian", "Jaden"],
    ["Brian", "Jaden", "Tessa"],
]

names_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Previous", "Current", "Next"])

hg1 = graphistry.hypergraph(names_df,
                            entity_types=["Previous", "Current", "Next"],
                            direct=True,
                            opts={
                                'CATEGORIES': {
                                    'person': ["Previous", "Current", "Next"]
                                    },
                                'EDGES': {
                                    "Previous": ["Current"],
                                    "Current": ["Next"]
                                }
                                }
                            )

hg1_g = hg1["graph"]
hg1_g.plot()
```

Edit: you can also specify your edges with `'EDGES'` inside `opts`. See `hypergraph` [docstring](https://github.com/graphistry/pygraphistry/blob/37e90ce702434e7fd79bc46c0ab319a7b9c51694/graphistry/pygraphistry.py#L869)

Note that you don't need to specify entity type in this case since you're using all columns.